# I have an error building my TSX-Expo-React Native application: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, build, react-native-code-push

When I build my application with eas build with expo, everything is correct, only at the end this error appears. I have read a lot and I have not been able to solve it. If someone can guide me, that would be great.
I show code...

Running 'gradlew :app:assembleDebug' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
10
%.
20%.
30%
40%
50%.
60
%.
70%
80%
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:

- Support for Java 18
- Support for building with Groovy 4
- Much more responsive continuous builds
- Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution
  For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/release-notes.html
  To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
  Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar
> Configure project :expo-application
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-av
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 accepted.
> Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)".
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" ready.
> Installing NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" complete.
> "Install NDK (Side by side) 23.1.7779620 (revision: 23.1.7779620)" finished.
> Checking the license for package CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package CMake 3.22.1 accepted.
> Preparing "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)".
> "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" ready.
> Installing CMake 3.22.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1
> "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" complete.
> "Install CMake 3.22.1 (revision: 3.22.1)" finished.
> Configure project :expo-camera
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-constants
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-dev-client
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-dev-launcher
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-dev-menu
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-dev-menu-interface
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-file-system
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-font
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-image-loader
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-image-picker
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-json-utils
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-keep-awake
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-linear-gradient
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-location
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-manifests
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-media-library
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-permissions
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-sharing
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-splash-screen
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-system-ui
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo-updates-interface
> WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
> Configure project :expo
> Using expo modules

- expo-application (5.1.1)
- expo-av (13.2.1)
- expo-camera (13.2.1)
- expo-constants (14.2.1)
- expo-dev-client (2.1.3)
- expo-dev-launcher (2.1.3)
- expo-dev-menu (2.1.3)
- expo-file-system (15.2.2)
- expo-font (11.1.1)
- expo-image-loader (4.1.1)
- expo-image-picker (14.1.1)
- expo-json-utils (0.5.1)
- expo-keep-awake (12.0.1)
- expo-linear-gradient (12.1.1)
- expo-location (15.1.1)
- expo-manifests (0.5.2)
- expo-media-library (15.2.2)
- expo-modules-core (1.2.3)
- expo-permissions (14.1.1)
- expo-sharing (11.2.1)
- expo-splash-screen (0.18.1)
- expo-system-ui (2.2.1)
  WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
  Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
  License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
  Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
  "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.
  Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.3
  "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.
  "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.
  Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 33 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
  License for package Android SDK Platform 33 accepted.
  Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)".
  "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" ready.
  Installing Android SDK Platform 33 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-33
  "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" complete.
  "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" finished.
  [stderr]
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  [stderr]

- What went wrong:
  [stderr]
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  [stderr]

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> [stderr]
> Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push.
> [stderr]
> Required by:
> [stderr]
> project :app
> [stderr]
> > No matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.1' but:
> [stderr]
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
> [stderr]

- Try:
  [stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> [stderr]
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> [stderr]
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> [stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  [stderr]
  BUILD FAILED in 3m 6s
  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
  You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
  Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjc2J.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Iy1.png)

*WHEN I RUN EXPO DOCTOR IN MY PROJECT EVERYTHING GOES OK....*

I have tried to clear cache, reinstall libraries, recompile almost everything and I have not been able to solve it, I reinstalled dependencies, and the project works fine, the functionality of the app is very good, only the problem I have with that my suspicions are in react-native-code-push but i tried everything and nothing works, in ios if it works the problem is with android...